# Dynamic JavaScript to allow character input after limited with preventDefault

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a dynamic JavaScript rules engine in which based on criteria such as a dropdown is not changed, then I prevent any characters from being entered with:

```
$(document).on('keypress',"[id^="+condtionID+"]", function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); 
 });
```

However, if I change the dropdown to a value which does allow for any character, the textbox refuses to then allow for input.

Examples of IDs:

```
Select:  ID="selectNumber435"
Input:   ID="condtionID435"
```

Every row dynamically created into the table ends with the same random number created.

Problem is that once I do not allow any input, I tried:

```
return true;   did not work
```

Even another condition in which I only allow numeric, I change to a dropdown value that allows for all input and it "holds on to" thinking it should ONLY allow numeric.

I would prefer to not have to make the user delete the dynamically created row, there has to be a way to allow for typing characters into the input box again. Some sort of "Reset" ...

Comment: Did you try to simply `$(document).off('keypress', "[id^="+condtionID+"]");`?

Comment: Sweet!  :)  that works,  please create an answer @Félix so I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply dettach the attached event:

`$(document).off('keypress',"[id^="+condtionID+"]");`